# how set style display in opera?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, opera

I have this html code for my button:

```
<a href="process.php" id="processLink" style="display:none;">Click</a>
```

and this javascript code for set display style the button:

```
function setstyleint()
{
    var divArray = document.getElementById('processLink'); 
    divArray.style.display = 'initial';
}
```

it work in ff and chrome very good.
but in opera and ie(my version is 9) do not work,

is there any help?
best regards.

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: `divArray.style.display = '';`

Comment: What do you mean _do not work_? Not style is being set, is it set to initial but you don't want that, is the function being called?

Comment: i have a button before this one: <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="iframe.php" id="text_change1" onclick="setstyleint();">Upload!</a> ....

Comment: @user3425550 please share your complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `divArray.style.display = '';`
insted of  `divArray.style.display = 'initial';`

also commented by [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello)

Comment: thank you and epascarello... this works in IE and Opera.